# Strange error with a List of generic classes

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of Class objects, all of which need to extend a class with a generic type. Here is my code:

```
private final List<Class<? extends A<?>>> CLASS_LIST =
        Arrays.asList(B.class, C.class, D.class);

// Base class
private abstract class A<T extends Object> {}

// Some class that extends A
private class B extends A<String> {}

// Some other class that extends A
private class C extends A<String> {}

// A class that extends A, but with a different type than the first two
private class D extends A<OtherClass> {}

private static class OtherClass {}
```

This works fine, but if I remove D.class from the list I get an error saying:

```
Incompatible types, Required A<?>, found A<String>
```

Why does this happen? I assume that Java infers the type.... but why? And is there a way around it? I found that if i use `List<?>` it works in all cases, but then I lose type safety.

**EDIT:**
Also, if I then have this method:

```
private void Check(){
    A a = new B();

    if(CLASS_LIST.contains(a.getClass())){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

It gives me a warning for a suspicious call to `List.contains(...)`. However, if I use `List<?>`, the warning goes away.... why is this?

**EDIT2:**
Java 1.8.0_51-b16 compiles, but Java 1.7.0_79 gives the error.

Comment: Note, `A<T extends Object>` is there just for simplicity's sake, in reality it would extend something else.

Comment: I run without any error, did you mean CLASS_LIST = Arrays.asList(B.class, C.class); causes error?

Comment: Yes, that causes an error for me.  Using IntelliJ Ultimate 15, compiling with jdk 1.7.0_79, set to Java 7. If I try to compile it anyway it gives the Incompatible types error.

Comment: Huh, tried compiling directly with javac... Java 1.8.0_51-b16 compiles, but Java 1.7.0_79 gives the error.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, when you write

```
Arrays.asList(B.class, C.class)
```

The compiler (1.7, 1.8 is a bit better at type inference) infers a type of `Class<? extends A<String>>` from its arguments, which is incompatible with the assignment. You can work around by specifying the desired type like this:

```
Arrays.<Class<? extends A<?>>>asList(B.class, C.class)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you see the JDK source code.

The method Arrays.asList return an ArrayList is Arrays's innner class,not the java.util.ArrayList.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}

/**
* @serial include
*/
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
{
    ....
}
```

And the Arrays's inner class ArrayList does not override the `remove` method,so it throws an exception.

Comment: I think that by "I remove D.class", the OP meant removing from the source code.